# Redirect Customers to Forgot Password page after number of unsuccessful login attempts exceeded

Tags: customer, login, redirect-url

I want to know how can i redirect a user to the Forgot Password page after exceeding the number of unsuccessful login attempts in Magento 2. Thanks.

Comment: Make it redirection in your Login controller but i don't know number of Unsucess attempt

Comment: I have already set the number of unsuccessful attempts to 3. I just have to do the redirection. I'm new to Magento 2 btw.

Comment: Override this Controller in your Module vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/LoginPost.php there you need to set forget psw url Don't edit core file

Comment: Can you show me how to do that exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this and it works.

```
                $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
                $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/forgotPassword');
                return $resultRedirect;
```